# How to change meta title in prestashop module?

Tags: module, prestashop, meta-tags, prestashop-1.6, meta

I'm using prestashop 1.6 and one module is not editable in SEO&URL, to change is meta.
Actually, i have the default pretashop meta title.
How can i add a custom header.tpl for this module ?

Thank you for your help

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a module with a controller,
you can add in the base file `/modules/mymodule/mymodule.php`,
inside the method `__construct()`,
a object like this `$this->controllers = array('controller_file_name');`, where the `controller_file_name` is the file which generate the page in the front office.

Once made this, you will need to re-install the module and this added object will generate a new page in the SEO&URL where you could change all the metas (title, description and keywords).

You can see some examples of this modules in the bankwire, cheque and blocknewsletter.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I can't re-install this module, (video module)  i'll lose all my data and config...

Comment: I understand, you can force the page creation with this [code](https://codeshare.io/5MyzjR), assuming you have the object `$this->controllers`, just need execute that code once time.

Comment: I add the code in mymodule.php, and re-install the module
I have now the module in the section seo & url.  I change the meta, but when the page module is loading, i can see the new meta title in the browser for a second, and it change for the default title meta (shop name)..

Comment: Maybe you have changed something in other place, if you restore the code you have changed should works correctly.