# Change meta_tags meta_description and meta_name to a custom page which extends page.tpl in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I have a custom module which defines a custom page in Prestashop.
It consist on a template which extendes page.tpl and a front controller.

I would like to understand where shall I modify the metas for this specific page.

I see in this controller this part where the template is invoked:

```
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'link' =>            $this->context->link,
        'category'             => $this->category,
        'main_category_logo' => $image_url,
        'description_short'    => Tools::truncateString($this->category->description, 350),
        'sub_categories'    => $data,
        'body_classes'         => array($this->php_self.'-'.$this->category->id, $this->php_self.'-'.$this->category->link_rewrite),
        'search_url' => $this->context->link->getPageLink('search', null, null, null, false, null, true)
    ));

    $this->setTemplate('module:'.$this->module->name.'/views/templates/front/category.tpl');
```

Is this the right place to add the metas? How this shall be done?

Answer (score 2):

In PS 1.7 that's really easy modifying it in the tpl of a front controller.

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}

{block name='head_seo_title'}
    MY META TITLE
{/block}

{block name='head_seo_description'}
    MY META DESCRIPTION
{/block}

{block name='head_seo_keywords'}
    MY META KEYWORDS
{/block}
```

And here another option from SEO & URL from the back office: [How to change meta title in prestashop module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747636/how-to-change-meta-title-in-prestashop-module/51750111#51750111)

Comment: do you think this is possible to achieve from the Faceted Module by adding a tpl file? I'm trying to change meta title for filtered listing and I'm not finding a way to do it (as I was in the 1.6 version…)

Answer (score 1):

in PrestaShop 1.7, you also can create your own ***getTemplateVarPage()*** function in your ***ModuleFrontController*** class, calling the parent and set the meta variables as you want (useful for an item page type like blog article, news, store, ...), so you don't have to put logic in your template.

```
public function getTemplateVarPage()
{
    $page = parent::getTemplateVarPage();

    $page['meta']['title'] = 'MY META TITLE';
    $page['meta']['description'] = 'MY META DESCRIPTION';
    $page['meta']['keywords'] = 'MY META KEYWORDS';
    $page['meta']['robots'] = 'index'; // noindex, nofollow, none, ...

    return $page;
}
```

If it's a *static* page like a list or a mono page, you can add the controller and set the Meta information directly in the Back Office (SEO menu).

Good luck

Comment: do you think there's a way to do this from the Faceted Search Module? I've searched, by the is no ModuleFrontController within the module… I'm trying to change meta title for filtered listing pages and I'm not finding a way to do it (as I was in the 1.6 version…)